# Spring boot externalise properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot 1.5.1 with Java 8 , I am trying to pick up application.properties file from file system. My local dev env is Windows & Prod env is linux. The below code works well in local but not in linux env.

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:C:/conf/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@PropertySource(value = "file:/home/me/prod/props/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Comment: Don't use `@PropertySource` when starting specify the `config.location` instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate pls?

Comment: Why not are you using the environment profiling to segregate the properties files used for Local and Server? Spring/Boot empowers the developer such that, they can create code that is self-contained and environment agnostic. This shall indeed help you develop applications which are Cloud-Native in nature and never depends upon the system to provide it with any required data.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Martin said:

From the docs:

"If you don’t like application.properties as the configuration file name you can switch to another by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location using the spring.config.location environment property (comma-separated list of directory locations, or file paths)."

> $ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject

or

> $ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties